# GetResponse socketexception 10038 how to catch?

Tags: c#, wpf, websocket

It is funny but I can't catch it...
This error occurs only while "attach to proccess". When I start programm with VS2010 with debug or release there is no this error.

I try connect to **localhost:62917/api** and when the service(on this address) does not work I know that I get the exception, but I can't catch it, my programm crash only =(
**Error Code is 10038**

[image]

UPD: I need that when this error occurs programm catch it and continue work but not crush

Comment: if you step through does the code does it enter the catch block. You might have break on user-handled exceptions turned on?

Comment: 10038 is `WSAENOTSOCK`, "Socket operation on nonsocket.". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren  I have read it, but I do not know how it can solve my problem

Comment: No I wasn't suggesting that just knowing that might solve your problem, just wanted to add some extra information for others seeing this question.